# Why can't I open images uploaded to Google Drive using Dropzone and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, sails.js, dropzone.js

I've been trying to upload images using dropzone and save them in google drive. Here is the code

```
 data = google.drive({
                    version: "v3",
                    auth
                }).files.create({
                    media: {
                        mimeType: uploadFiles[0].type,
                        body: fullpath
                    },
                    requestBody: {
                        name: uploadFiles[0].filename,
                        mimeType: uploadFiles[0].type,
                        parents: [""]
                    },
                    fields: "id,name"
                }).then();
```

The thing is, it is uploading in google drive but the image is not opening neither on google drive nor when I download it. It says "It appears that we don't support this file format"

Can anyone help? Thanks

I don't really know what I can do to make this work. When I coded it at first, it was uploading the wrong format now it seems to be working correctly, just that little thing of not opening

Comment: As a troubleshooting step I would compare the size of the file you've uploaded to the size of the file you have on your disk. They should be exactly the same.

Comment: In your script, what are the values of `uploadFiles` and `fullpath`? And, can I ask you about the origin of the values?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I just needed to to `createReadStream` with the `fullpath`

```
data = await google.drive({
  version: "v3",
  auth
}).files.create({
  media: {
    mimeType: uploadFiles[0].type,
    body: fs.createReadStream(fullpath)
  },
  requestBody: {
    name: uploadFiles[0].filename,
    mimeType: uploadFiles[0].type,
    parents: [""]
  },
  fields: "id"
})
```